# Separating data structures from algorithms in Go

Tags: go, design-patterns, solid-principles, visitor-pattern

I'm currently building a compiler for a toy language in Go, to learn about Go and compilers in general. I have an AST that has heterogenous nodes (`AssignStatement`, `BinaryExpression`, `IfStatement`...) like,

```
type IfStatement struct {
    Meta           meta.Meta
    Condition      Expression
    IfBlock        []Statement 
    ElseBlock      []Statement 
}
```

To work with this data structure I was have been maintaining an interface which is implemented by all the nodes of the AST. For example,

```
type Statement interface {
    TypeCheck(state *TypeCheckState)
}
```

All statement nodes will implement their specific `TypeCheck` methods using metadata from `state` and calling the `TypeCheck` method on their children nodes. It has worked well enough but as I keep progressing in building my compiler this interface has become bloated and I don't feel like many of the methods belong there. Like I probably will have to add a `TranslateToLLVMInstruction` method on this interface when I get to backend. I want to decouple the AST data structure from these methods. I have looked at the Visitor pattern but it doesn't seem to fit very well in this recursive scenario where each visiting action might need different parameters and return values. With my current approach I can define whatever method signature I want for each action.

How are these situations usually handled in Go?

Comment: Take a look at the ast package in the stdlib. Decorating ast types with logic may work to some extent. The alternative is to use the `ast` as a data structure, and write multiple passes to go over it, and build additional data structures.